# Create "File-Drop (Upload Only)" share in NextCloud using WebDav

Tags: asp.net, nextcloud

Using NextCloud, I was wondering if it is possible to create a "FileDrop (Upload Only)" share using WebDav. I couldn't find any documentation regarding this, neither on NextClouds website, nor in the WebDav RFC specifications. It is a feature on the Nextcloud webinterface.

I'm using .NET using a WebDav Client library

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer. Posting it here in case someone stumbles upon it.

To share a folder on Nextcloud using API, you need to use the OCS Share API instead of WebDav
[OCS Sharing API](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/developer_manual/core/ocs-share-api.html)

One needs to create a share with permissions set to 'Create == 4, shareType == 3'

EDIT:
It's been a while since I wrote this code, but I hope it still works. Haven't tested it since as in the end I didn't use the code in my project.

```
 public class NextCloud
{
    private INextCloudConfig _config;
    private HttpClient _client;
    public NextCloud(INextCloudConfig config, string userName, string password)
    {
        _config = config;
        var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password);
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(credentials));

    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateFolderAsync(string path)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("MKCOL"), _config.WebDavAddress + "/" + path);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        return response;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateShareAsync(string path, ShareType shareType, Permissions permissions)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), new Uri(_config.OCSAddress + "/shares?format=json"));
        request.Headers.Add("OCS-APIRequest", "true");

        var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("shareType", ((int)shareType).ToString()));
        parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("shareWith", null));
        parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("path", path));
        parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("permissions", ((int)permissions).ToString()));
        //parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("publicUpload", "true"));
        
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);

        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var json = JsonDocument.Parse(responseContent);

        return response;
    }
}

public interface INextCloudConfig
{
    string WebDavAddress { get; }
    string OCSAddress { get; }
}

public class NextCloudConfig : INextCloudConfig
{
    private const string DEFAULTWEBDAVSUFFIX = "remote.php/webdav/";
    private const string DEFAULTOCSSUFFIX = "ocs/v2.php/apps/files_sharing/api/v1/";

    private static string _baseAddress = "";
    private static string _webdavSuffix = "";
    private static string _ocsSuffix = "";

    public string WebDavAddress
    {
        get => _baseAddress + "/" + _webdavSuffix;
    }

    public string OCSAddress
    {
        get => _baseAddress + "/" + _ocsSuffix;
    }

    public NextCloudConfig(string baseAddress) : this(baseAddress, DEFAULTWEBDAVSUFFIX, DEFAULTOCSSUFFIX)
    {
        
    }

    public NextCloudConfig(string baseAddress, string webdavSuffix, string ocsSuffix)
    {
        _baseAddress = baseAddress.TrimEnd('/');
        _webdavSuffix = webdavSuffix.TrimEnd('/');
        _ocsSuffix = ocsSuffix.TrimEnd('/');
    }

}

public enum Permissions
{
    Read = 1,
    Update = 2,
    Create = 4, 
    Delete = 8,
    Share = 16,
    All = 31
}

public enum ShareType
{
    User = 0,
    Group = 1,
    PublicLink = 3
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Run().Wait();
}

public static async Task Run()
{
    NextCloudConfig config = new NextCloudConfig("https://url.to.nexcloudinstance");
    NextCloud nc = new NextCloud(config, "john.doe@gmail.com", "passw0rd");
    await nc.CreateFolderAsync(path);
    await nc.CreateShareAsync(path, ShareType.PublicLink, Permissions.Create);

    Console.ReadLine();
 
}
```

That's the code from my test project. It's a simple command prompt application. I hope that helps you. The link I posted still works and provides additional information on the different enums.

Comment: can you elaborate how you did it a bit more please

Comment: @Fuseteam : see my edit

Comment: thank you! i'll check if i can make use of this